# search engine friendly url for search query strings in php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on `php` actually I need SEO urls for search queries script I have written in folder called as `newtheme` (folder name). When I try to do SEO urls not working not found showing when perform search. Please check my code and correct me where i did wrong.

in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^searchword=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^results.php$ /newtheme/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

In my results.php

```
if($_GET['searchword'];
{
$q= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['searchword']);
$sql=mysql_query("select * from table where keyword='$q'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row['title'];
}
?>
```

htaccess file placed at my folder inside as newtheme. script folder localhost/newtheme/.htaccess

Comment: You should read about SQL injection and the `mysql_*` functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: You need to provide more details like what is your link URL? What is location of this .htaccess etc.

Comment: @anubhava search form code       <form id="cdo-search-form" autocomplete="off" action="results.php" method="get"><input type="text" id="searchword" name="searchword"  style="width:100%!important;" /></form>

Answer (score 0):

As an absolute minimum, PLEASE escape the search word before you feed it into the MySQL query.

```
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['searchword']);
```

If I understand your implementation correctly, you're trying to SEF rewrite a query against your results.php file which is located in the newtheme directory, try something like this

```
RewriteRule ^searchword/([\ A-Za-z0-9-_,]+)?$ /newtheme/results.php?searchword=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not working, sef url showing like results.php?searchword=rose. but i need as http://localhost/newtheme/search/rose

Comment: in search form field name i used as searchword, action page is results.php, general it is working http://localhost/newtheme/results.php?searchword=rose, i need as http://localhost/newtheme/search/rose

Answer (score 0):

You will need these 2 rules in your `/newtheme/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newtheme/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+newtheme/results\.php\?searchword=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^search/([^/.]+)/?$ results.php?searchword=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: still not working i have changed as you told, browser url showing results.php?searchword=something when perform search.

Comment: Ok what is location of above .htaccess? And what is your full URL in browser that didn't work?

Comment: Is it `/newtheme/results.php?searchword=something` OR just `/results.php?searchword=something`?

Comment: when i perform search url showing like this http://localhost/newtheme/results.php?searchword=Wax+flower

Comment: Then make sure above .htaccess is in `/newtheme/.htaccess` and before all other rules there.

Comment: when i change like this rule RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+newtheme/results\.php\?searchword=([^\s&]+) [NC]
working but template css and images not loading please suggest me

Comment: url rewrite is working but theme template css, images not loading please help. now url coming like this http://localhost/newtheme/search/Suffron

Comment: Make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Thank You Anubhava. It's working now. Once again thank You. Great.